# Can zero be in the least element in a proof of mathematical induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, binary, well-orders

The Well-Ordering Principle states that every non-empty set of positive integers has a least element.  However, would this also apply to any non-empty set of non-negative integers (including zero)?  I don't see why not, but I wanted to check in case I've missed something.

I wanted to prove that for every n (where n = greatest power of 2 in the left binary number in the equation), the following base 2 number equivalences hold.  For example:

1 = 0 + 1      (all numbers in base 2).

10 = 01 + 1

100 = 011 + 1

1000 = 0111 + 1

10000 = 01111 + 1

etc...

Since the lowest power of 2 in the left binary number is 0 (see the first equation) the least element in my proof must be n = 0.

I was able to successfully prove it with Induction, assuming that the least element is allowed to be zero.

Comment: Yes it's fine.  Exercise to you is to state this as a theorem and prove it :)

Comment: "However, would this also apply to any non-empty set of non-negative integers (including zero)? " of course.  Either zero is not in the set and it has a least as it is all positive, or zero is in the set and zero is the least element as zero is the least non negative interger.

Comment: The least element can be 1,0, 35, or -56 or anything you want.  Numbers aren't magic and they aren't poetry.   All that matters is that the numbers go from one to the next, and that can happen no matter where you start.

Comment: @fleablood Makes sense.  So proving something in a non-empty subset of positive integers can always be attempted with induction due to always having a least element.  However, proving something in a non-empty subset of all integers can not always be attempted with induction; but, when a least element does exist, then it can be done with induction?

Comment: You can do induction on the integers (or any countable set) if you can prove $P(a_n) \implies P(a_{n\pm 1})$.  Example $e^x > 0$ for all integers $x$.  Proof:  Base case: $e^0 = 1> 0$.  Induction step: $e > 0$ then if $e^n > 0$ then $e^{n-1} = \frac {e^n}e > 0$ and $e^{n+1} = e*e^n > 1$.  You can even do induction on the rationals *if* you have an ordering and *if* you can do the induction step.

Comment: @fleablood Understood, thanks for clarifying this.  In your example though, wouldn't it be impossible to do a base case?  You're trying to prove e^x > 0 for all integers x.  The least integer does not exist since there's no least negative integer.

Comment: Pick any ding-donged base element you like.  If you can prove it for k=2,317 and if true for any k then true for any $k\pm 1$ then true for 2,318 and 2,316 and eventually all integers.  Does it matter that 2,317 isn't the least case? No, that isn't worth a hill of beans. Any number can be a base case.

Comment: @fleablood I respectfully disagree.  The purpose of the base case is to set up the argument:  k ==> k + 1     By proving the least element (for this example let's call it 1) is true, and then by proving the argument above, you can prove the entire statement is true for 1 and 2, then 2 and 3, and so on until infinity.  But let's say you prove the statement is true for k = 5.  Even if you prove k => k + 1, how do you know the statement is true for any values of k less than 5?  You can keep repeating to infinity to know all values of k >= 5 make the statement true, but not values < 5.

Comment: You are talking one-way induction with one induction step.  I am talking two way induction with two induction step**s**.  If you prove that if a statement is true for $n$ then it is true for $n +1$ *AND* you prove it is true for $n-1$ then that is two induction steps and if you prove it is true for any ding-donged integer at all it is true for all integers.  Ex. i) $e^{27}>2^{27}=134217728> 0$. $e>0$ ii) If $e^n > 0$ then $e^{n+1} = e^n*e >0$ so $e^n>0$ for all $n\ge 27$, iii) if $e^n>0$ then $e^{n-1}=\frac {e^n}e > 0$.  So $e^n > 0$ for all $n\le 27$.  So $e^n > 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Let's get back to your very first question. You asked if you can do induction on a set in which 1 was not the least element.  The answer is yes.  Induction doesn't care where you start.  And it doesn't care what direction it goes in.  All it cares is that i) you start somewhere ii) that from any point you can get an immediate successor (or predecessor) and iii) going through the all successors goes through all elements.  Which btw requires *more* than just being well ordered.

Comment: A well ordered set means that  every set has a least element.  As an immediate result that means every element has an immediate successor.  Thus by induction you can construct a set generated by a single element.  But it doesn't mean you can generate a well ordered set by a single generator.  Ex: Let A={ (n,m)} for all natural n,m with (n,m)< (k,j) if n <k and (n,m)<(n,j) if m< j. (The lexicographical order) is well order but you can't do induction on it as the successor of (1,m) is (1,m+1) and you'd never get to (2,1) which doesn't have a *pre*decessor.

Comment: Interesting, I never considered going both ways with induction, which would allow you to attempt a proof on something like all the integers.  When you said to pick any element I like, I thought you were talking about standard one way induction.  For two way induction, I'd see how any number would work.  Also, I know a set needs to be more than well ordered for induction to work; the only reason I mentioned that in my question was in the interest of picking a least element.